Как настроить внедрение на сайт EXEL-файла из OneDrive с привязкой к наименованию в строке
В OneDrive функционал "внедрение" на сайт EXEL-файла реализован с возможностью выделения конкретной ячейки в строке (например A652).
Нам нужно настроить с выделением "по наименованию" в строке (например Kids 284).
Пробовали ActiveItem='TDSheet'!Kids 284 - не работает.
Что делаем неверно?
Пример кода:
<iframe  width="100%" height="110%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=E578C9080C56B55A&resid=E578C9080C56B55A%21137188&authkey=AEJbMZ1vY9fuED8&em=2&AllowTyping=True&ActiveCell='TDSheet'!A652&wdHideGridlines=True&wdInConfigurator=True&wdInConfigurator=True&edesNext=false&resen=false"</iframe>

